# Removing duplicate characters in a String array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

I have a sample input like [q w e r r t] and I want to remove duplicates and print [q w e r t] with arrays. I don't see why the output is different for the below code snippet.

```
for(int j=0; j< array.length; j++) {
    for(int k=j+1; k< array.length; k++) {
        if(array[j] == array[k]) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
        j = k;
    }
}
```

Update:  I wanted to use this logic for a sorted array. I used Arrays.sort(). I changed == to .equals() for Strings.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    // Enter size of array and assert the type of input
    System.out.println("Enter size of array in integers");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter integers");
        sc.next();
    }
    ;

    // Accepting the values into the array and sorting them
    int demoInt = sc.nextInt();
    String[] array = new String[demoInt];
    String[] outputMarkers = new String[demoInt];
    System.out.println("Enter the values");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Scanner scNum = new Scanner(System.in);
        array[i] = scNum.next();
        if (i == array.length - 1) System.out.println("Array is full");
    }
    Arrays.sort(array);
    System.out.printf("Sorted array is : %s", Arrays.toString(array));

    //Checking for duplicates //Sample: a a a s d f
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < array.length; k++) {
            if (array[j].equals(array[k])) {
                continue; //returns to for loop with increment
            }
            System.out.print(array[j] + ". ");
            j = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Input: a a a d f
Output: a d f

Comment: I do not want to use any collections.

Comment: `equals` to be used when use are using `String`

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: Sorted array is : [a, a, d, f, s]     Output is a. d. f.

Comment: put the type of array you are using... so people can help you

Comment: @Tommy I have edited the title after RAZ_Muh_Taz mentioned it.

Comment: @lft93ryt it should be _"in **a** String array"_ not _"in **an** String Array"_

Comment: @VictorC. grammar Nazi? Really? just making a suggestion. I'd rather not waste peoples time by making them review that trivial mistake. The op could do that easily, which is why I told him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are checking each character against all the characters after it. Imagine an array with no duplicates; once you get to the last character, you have printed out all the characters before it. But when `j = array.length - 1`, then `k = array.length`, and the second `for` loop does not run at all, and your last character will never be printed.

Your code would always fail to print the last element correctly. The only case in which it would be correct is if your last element is a duplicate of a previous element, but not of the second-to-last element.

Try this code instead:

```
outerloop:
for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    for(int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
        if(array[j] == array[k]) {
                continue outerloop;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
}
```

The premise of the code is that it loops through each of the characters. If it matches any of the previous characters, the code skips that element and continues to the next one.

EDIT: Looks like you edited the question for a sorted array instead. That means if the last element is a duplicate, it will be a duplicate of the element before it so we don't have to worry about the corner case in my previous block of code.

```
for(int j=0; j< array.length; j++) {
    for(int k=j+1; k< array.length; k++) {
        if(array[j] == array[k]) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
        j = k;
    }
}
System.out.print(array[array.length-1] + " ");
```

Comment: I really don't think it matters in this simple case. OP just wants a quick-to-code algorithm to do this instead of some optimized code that will run half a millisecond faster. If he really wanted efficiency he would be using a `Set`. Besides, I'm just using what he had in his original code.

Comment: Wow I totally missed out on printing the other half of the case. @VictorC. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove the values rather than just skip over them when printing, you will want to start from the end of your array and work towards 0, calling array.remove(i) when you find an object that matches a previously checked object.

Though that is just to do it as a loop exercise. It would be easier to push your array into a Set.

Comment: Totally agree! I would not have to go through this if I were to use a Set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Boolean array of size 122, make all the values in the array as false, iterate the give character array, if the ASCII value of character is false, thena make it true and print it.
Below is the example code, here I have taken a string and removing all the duplicates and printing the resulting string:

```
static String removeDuplicate(String s) {
    boolean[] flagArr = new boolean[122];
    int sLength = s.length();
    StringBuilder resultStr = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++) {
        char tempChar = s.charAt(i);
        int tempVal = (int) tempChar;
        if (!flagArr[tempVal]) {
            flagArr[tempVal] = true;
            resultStr.append(tempChar);
        }
    }
    return resultStr.toString();
}
```

The complete code is at

[Removing Duplicate Characters From String Without Using Set |  jain Tarun Blog](http://tarunjain-jaintarun.blogspot.in/2017/08/removing-duplicate-characters-from.html)

Comment: Nobody said anything about ASCII. The range of char is [Character.MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_VALUE) to [Character.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE). Of course, char is a UTF-16 code unit and removing duplicate code units doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use only one loop ?

```
//assuming array has length >= 2
System.out.print(array[0] + " ");
for(int j=1; j< array.length; j++) {
    if(array[j] == array[j - 1]) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
}
```

Comment: Because that only detects duplicates that are next to each other